# How to Override Magento 2 vendor files

Tags: magento2

How to override addtocart.phtml files to change "Add to cart" button name.

Answer (score 5):

You can use theme translation at here.

Create {LanguageCode}.csv at

```
 __/app
     |__/design
       |__/frontend
         |__/<Vendor>
           |__/<theme>
             |__/i18n
               |-- {LanguageCode}.csv
```

***At this csv, "Add to Cart","MYCart"***.

See more detail at https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.3/frontend-dev-guide/translations/xlate.html

After that, you need to run static content deploy for getting affect of the translation.

Comment: That a good criteria to update just title all over the website. +1

Comment: Great answer and Better criteria to update through translation dictionaries. +1

Answer (score 2):

Try overide with you theme file

Copy the file from below path

> vendor/magento/module-catalog/view/frontend/templates/product/view/addtocart.phtml

then paste it in below path

> app/design/frontend/{Package}/{theme-name}/Magento_Catalog/templates/product/view/addtocart.phtml

clean cache and check.

**EDIT :**

In order to change label see @Amit answer, that would be simple.

Answer (score 1):

You need to overwrite addtocart.phtml file with in your theme directory.

Copy the addtocart.phtml file from

```
vendor/magento/module-catalog/view/frontend/templates/product/view/addtocart.phtml
```

to

```
app/design/frontend/<vendor-name>/<theme-name>/Magento_catalog/templates/product/view/addtocart.phtml
```

and make edit as you wants on this phtml file.

Flush the cache and refresh the page. I hope this helps.

Comment: app/design/frontend/magento
then no any folder here.

Comment: It seems you have not created a custom theme yet. for the best practice you need to create a custom theme and apply it. Please following the official guide for it: https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.2/frontend-dev-guide/themes/theme-create.html and https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.2/frontend-dev-guide/themes/theme-apply.html

Comment: Also I agree with @Amit answer, that would be simple in order to change just label.